# Forking threads is not speeding up my program, am I correctly using it in my situation?

Tags: java, multithreading

I think I’m using threads wrong so I wanted to ask if this was good design.  Basically I have a program that pulls data from a queue then processes it(processing is pure math so its 100% cpu intensive), then if the data is good its send to a ‘good’ queue otherwise its either completely discarded or part of it is sent back to the initial ‘work’ queue for further processing.  That’s the high level logic of it and when my queue was in-memory my program used all cores and was really fast. As my data grows I decided to use a queue server to store the queue and then distribute the processing over multiple machines and now its slow(only 40%-60% of each core is being used).

I tried to profile my code(using yourkit and the built in one in netbeans) and it says most of the time(80%) is spent on the queue program.  I thought I can maybe keep the number crunching going constantly in my program by pushing all external program stuff to another thread, but its not helping with performance and I’m wondering if I’m dong it wrong.  I am not sure, but I’m wondering if a launch a thread(child-thread) from an existing thread(parent-thread), does the child one have to be complete before the parent one can finish?

My code is quite large and 99% is not needed, so I’ll just write a high level version of it(it may not compile but should give you an idea of what I’m doing).

```
public class worker {

    private static ExecutorService executor;
    static {
        final int numberOfThreads = 4;
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numberOfThreads, numberOfThreads, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>());    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ShutdownSignalException, ConsumerCancelledException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("starting worker..");
        //Connection information goes here
        channel.basicQos(50); //this is part of the connection, the queue server only gives 50 messages without acknowledgment

        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(); //gets data from queue
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());  
            executor.submit(new DoWork(channel, message, delivery));
        }

class DoWork implements Runnable{ //where the main work happens
    //setup variables, basically passing queue connection information as well as data here, so I only need to rely on one connection    
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Awk_to_Queue(channel, delivery)).start(); //this sends an Awk_to_Queue to the queue, I launch a thread for this so my program can keep working.

        if (data is good) {
            new Thread(new Send_to_Queue("success_queue", message1, channel)).start();                
            continue;
        }  else if (Data is not good but not bad either ) {
        new Thread(new Send_to_Queue("task_queue", message2, channel)).start();             
        } 

class Send_to_Queue implements Runnable{       
    public void run() {
        //takes data in and sends to queue in the way I used to previous do it, but just does it in a thread. queue connection is passed over so I only need to have one connection
    }
}


class Awk_to_Queue implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        //awk's queue so queue server can send one more piece of data to queue up
    }
}
```

There it is. I'm sorry if its a bit hard to read(I deleted a lot of stuff just to show you structure of what I'm doing).  What am I doing wrong that forking threads did not affect speed(It don't see it going faster nor is the profiler's results changed)? Is the problem with the way I'm forking threads ( `new Thread(new Awk_to_Queue(channel, delivery)).start();`) or is it something else like my design of threading?

Comment: It sure feels like too many threads to me; what's the benefit of shoving the queue submission into its own short-lived thread? How many processes are eventually running once this thing is under load?

Comment: @sarnold good question, when I look at the program it shows that 4 threads are running labeled thread1-1(-2,-3,etc) and then another set of 4 in thread2..not sure if thats the right answer. Do you think its better to launch another executor that process 1 or 2 queues at a time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

1) The only thread *reading* the remote queue appears to be the main thread running your infinite loop in the main() method.  However fast you stuff things into it, you'll never process them faster than you can take them back out.

2) Spawning `new Thread();`s is an "expensive" operation.  Constantly creating new threads for single short tasks is just churning through memory allocation and native resources.  You should offload those "queue puts" to a second `ExecutorService` that you can tune the size of, rather than spawning an unbounded number of threads.

Comment: Good point, I'll try your two suggestions. I know how to do point 2 but not sure of point1.  Other than a infinite while loop how do I keep reading the queue?  I did set QoS that provides my program with 50 pieces of work, but I only run 4 threads does that have the same effect?

Comment: That depends on if `consumer.nextDelivery();` and the consumer object are threadsafe.  If they are, you just put the loop code inside N new threads.

Comment: Thanks, they are thread safe, I'll try out your idea.  One last question, If I replace new Thread() with ExecutorService will it have  any impact that I'm launching it within a thread?  I'm asking because if I run launch threads in main my program will not end until all the threads are finished.  In my case will DoWork have to wait until Send_to_Queue is done or is it completely independent?

Comment: By default, no, doWork would not wait until send to queue is done unless you go out of your way to block the thread on the result.

Comment: You can also use a small BlockingQueue that the Consumer puts data into, and that the Producer reads from. That way you can buffer a few inputs, and a few outputs to try and keep your processing threads from waiting for a receive/send. Just run the ExecutorService with X threads that have access to the BlockingQueue's, then infinite loop on the take/put methods.

Comment: Another thing to check on is the underlying resource access.  Did you write the network code?  If all of those "sendToQueue"s are bumping into the same synchronization block against a single socket under the hood, then all the Threads in the world won't speed anything up.

Comment: Affe - How do I check that? I'm using rabbitmq's java client, it seems pretty widely used but I don't know for sure how to detect this issue(do I do it via profiling or by checking network activity on the server?)   @Drizzt321 good idea, I'll see if I can try it out, it seems a bit complex of managing two separate resource pools(I'm still learning but I'll give it a shot).

Comment: RabbitMQ should be fine, I'd bet that it's doing some actual threading under the hood to handle the connections, but the Consumer/Producer are still single threaded (per object) like ActiveMQ is. That's probably not going to be a big consumer of CPU time, especially if you disconnect the consumer/producer calls from your heavy computation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm learning and pretty slow.  I ended up switching what I was doing and created double the number of threads I had per cpu core and created two execution services, one for awks(which I gave more threads) and one for adding to the queue(which it a lower priority so I gave it less threads). I put a infinite while loop in each doWork loop that shared its the connection but had its own channel.  I got about 15%(its running at about 70 per core) more cpu usage but still not 100%.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest asking from rabbitMQ users the correct way to initialize/use the client to increase the parallelization of your gets and puts.  I have only used activeMQ personally.